# Functional equations about Conway's box function

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, special-functions

Conway's box function is the inverse of Minkowski's question mark function. It maps the dyadic rationals on the unit interval to the rationals using the Stern-Brocot tree (Farey sequence). 
The question is are there functional equations known about the function, which would allow recursive computation?